# pkg ]add command never returns

Tags: installation, julia, julia-pkg

New to julia. When I try to add a pkg via a julia prompt, the `add` command never returns to the command prompt in powershell. Same behavior in the default console in the windows julia install.

```
(v1.3) pkg> add Gadfly
   Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\omort\.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
    Fetching: [========================================>]  99.9 %
```

The gadfly install docs say to hit `delete` to return to the prompt, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Seems to work ok in bash on Ubuntu. What am I missing?

Following David Varela's suggestion below:

```
(v1.3) pkg> registry update General
[ Info: registry `General` not found.
```

However - running a bare `registry update` did push the command forward, though it errored out:

```
(v1.3) pkg> add Gadfly
   Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\omort\.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: SystemError: opening file "C:\\Users\\omort\\.julia\\registries\\General\\Registry.toml": No such file or directory
Stacktrace:[...]
```

The ~/.julia directory exists, but that toml file does not.

Note: I was able to get this working effortlessly on a second Windows laptop this morning, so it's something specific to this install.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `libgit2` not updating the registries properly. Have you tried `pkg> registry update General`?

Comment: @DavidVarela see my edits above - thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Removing .julia and reinstalling the julia package seems to have fixed it. Almost like the `add` command is waiting for something to time out - it takes quite a few minutes to return...